# How to connect SCSI-2 External Hard Drive with HD50 connector to PC?

Tags: external-hard-drive, compatibility, scsi

Is there a way I could connect my **HD50-connector** SCSI2 external hard drive to a PC and have it recognize it as a standard drive?

I would like to avoid solutions like the extremely rare and expensive SCSItoUSB cables. Are there SCSI2 interfaces that work with modern PCs maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is assuming when you say PC, you are not referring to a laptop.

Your looking for a PCI SCSI card with external HD-50 connector.

Something similar to this [Adaptec SCSI Card 29160N SCSI-2](http://storagetekpro.com/adaptec-scsi-card-29160n-scsi2-ultra160-scsi-controller-32bit-pci-high-density-hd-50pin-external-connector-p-1811.html) adapter.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm going to see next week if I can pick one up, seems like the best, cheapest and most straightforward solution! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your original question asking about printer parallel ports and SCSI:

Iomega Jaz drives and Zip100 drives had an adapter and software that allowed the SCSI drive to be connected using the "Jaz Traveller"(parallel port) adapter. It is not a fast way do access a drive (much < 2MB/s). I think it was SCSI-2 drive. If you can find one these Traveller adapters (see image in link it is the forest green dongle you see inline with the cable). The link shows that non-Iomega drives could be used with their [parallel adapter](http://micha.freeshell.org/traveller/index.html) but not an easy task.

I am not aware of any other vendors that were providing an adapter like this one. This tech is from mid 1990's when WIN 98SE was in use. The page mentions "Fortunately normal hostadapter drivers for the Jaz Traveller exists" you will need to reach out to the author to clarify that. This is not a complete answer to you problem but I hope it leads you to a solution. What version of windows are you using?

I still have my JAZ drives and adapter in a box somewhere. These adapters were a bit picky sometimes you needed to turn of enhanced features on parallel port in BIOS. Do post if you find something similar. A PCI SCSI-2 card would be a simpler (expected throughput 10MB/s).

Comment: Lol Jazz drives? Iomega zip drives? Your giving me a nostalgic moment over here. 

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, it seems that the best option is to install a PCI SCSI interface, I've found a place near me where they have loads of old pc scrap so I'm going to pay them a visit next week and see if they have any of those old cards kicking around! Thanks!